# How to check in array multidimentional array and add if not exists

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, yii2

Suppose i have array like this which i get from database:

```
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 03
            [percentage] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 04
            [percentage] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 05
            [percentage] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 07
            [percentage] => 12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 10
            [percentage] => 15
        )

    )
```

But what i need to do is if hour does not exist in array i.e 1,2,6,8,9,11,12; I need to push hour in array with my percentage value 0
ie

```
(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 01
                [percentage] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 02
                [percentage] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 03
            [percentage] => 20
        )
........
    [12] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 12
            [percentage] => 0
       )
```

Can some give any hint how to work with this. I need to check for every hour in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Required: Provide entries for all 12 hours.

[Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/524965)

#### Code:

```
$source = Array(
            array('hour' => 04, 'percentage' => 40),
            array('hour' => 05, 'percentage' => 10),
            array('hour' => 07, 'percentage' => 10),
            array('hour' => 10, 'percentage' => 15),
          );


$allHours = array(); // add all empty entries, in the correct order
                     // note: Index starts at one not zero! It is easier

for ($hour = 1; $hour <= 12; $hour++) { 
    $allHours[$hour] = array( 'hour' => $hour,  'percentage' => 0);
}

// replace existing ones
foreach($source as $entry) {
    $hour = $entry['hour'];
    $allHours[$hour] = $entry;
}

print_r($allHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let $hour & $percent are new values

```
If (!array_search($hour,         array_column($myarray, 'hour'))) {
  $myarray[] = array ('hour' => $hour, 'percentage' => $percent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post My answer may be it willl help for You

```
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
                {
                    if(!in_array( $i, array_column($data,'hour'))){
                       array_push($data,array('hour'=>$i,'percentage' =>     $percentage));
                    //$datas[] =array('hour'=>$hour,'percentage' =>         $percentage);
                    }

                }
```